# Change Form "pending_payment" to "processing"

Tags: orders, payment

With **PayPal-Payment** Magento works with a **"pending_payment"**.
This is the state the order gets if the customer is placed the order but is not ready with the payment;

Most times **PayPal-Payment** succeeds, so the **"pending_payment"** goes with **IPN** (Instant Payment Notification) to "processing". In some times the **PayPal-Payment** is been interrupted (customer bank account run out of money). This orders will be canceled.

In few times **PayPal** succeeds but the **IPN** is not working, so we find a Payment in PayPal account, but the order stucks to **"pending_payment"**. 
HOW CAN WE CHANGE THE STATE MANUALLY (backend or php).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for change `state` from pending payment to processing

```
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$order->save();
```